# How to set some properties and get instance of undefined class in Java using generic method

Tags: java, generics

**Question was updated with more information**

I have a test class and after creating instance of this class i need to get instance of new class and perform some action

```
public class searchTest {
    WebDriver driver;
    serchPage objSearch;
    searchResults objResults;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setup() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://google.com");
    }

    @Test
    public void testSearch() {
        page = new serchPage(driver);
        page.get(Widget.class, "Name").click()

    }


}
```

serchPage class:

```
public class serchPage {
    WebDriver driver;
    By searchText = By.xpath("//div(@class='page1')");

    public serchPage(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;

    }

    WebElement parentWebElement = driver.findElement(searchText);


    public <T> T get(Class<T> expectedElment, String name) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {

        T newObj = expectedElment.newInstance();
        newObj.setParent(parentWebElement);
        newObj.setName(name);

        return newObj;
    }

}
```

Widget class (the object which i want to get):

```
public class widget{
    WebDriver driver;
    String widgetName;
    By widgetFind = By.xpath("//label[text()='"+widgetName+"']/ancestor::div[contains (@class, 'widget ')]");


    public widget (WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void click() {
        setParent().findElement(widgetFind).click();
    }

    public WebElement setParent(WebElement parentWebElement) {
        WebElement parent = parentWebElement;
        return parent;
    }

    public String setName(String name) {
        widgetName = name;
        return widgetName;
    }

}
```

I'm looking for solution with using generic method **get** in serchPage class:

```
 public <T> T get(Class<T> expectedElment, String name) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {

            T newObj = expectedElment.newInstance();
            newObj.setParent(parentWebElement);
            newObj.setName(name);

            return newObj;
        }
```

The Question is how to **setParent** and **setName** for instance of Widget class

Comment: You have to set bound for T if you want to invoke .set on the object of T.

Comment: Since you say it doesn't work, I assume you've tried it.  Give us what you have tried, with real classnames; include the error message (not your transcription of what it says, but the actual message with line numbers, etc., and when it occurs).  It is much easier to help if we have something real to work with.  Without that, it is difficult to tell just what you want.

Comment: "does't working" is not proper problem description. You need to explain how it doesn't work and why you think it should work (maybe some documentation fragment). Also post code which will let us reproduce your problem.

Comment: ok, i give more info and description, i thought that my problem is obviously for experienced developers

Comment: It may be true, but purpose of Stack Overflow is to create library of good questions and answers, so as asker you are expected to make your question as clear as possible, so even non-experienced developers would be able to understand problem you are facing. This also benetifts you because you are increasing your chances of getting better answers (and getting them sooner).

Comment: ok, understand you and agree

Comment: Question was updated

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options:

1. **You could either tight your implementation to `widget` class directly**:

   ```
   public <T extends widget> T get(Class<T> expectedElment, String name) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
       T newObj = expectedElment.newInstance();
       newObj.setParent(parentWebElement);
       newObj.setName(name);

       return newObj;
   }
   ```

   In this case compiler would know that the class it creates will be at least `Widget` or any of its subclasses allowing you to call `Widget` methods.
2. **You could also extract the methods into an interface which Widget and other classes could implement**:

   ```
   public interface WidgetInterface {
       public WebElement setParent(WebElement parentWebElement);

       public String setName(String name);}
   }

   public class widget implements WidgetInterface {...}

   public <T extends WidgetInterface> T get(Class<T> expectedElment, String name) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
       T newObj = expectedElment.newInstance();
       newObj.setParent(parentWebElement);
       newObj.setName(name);

       return newObj;
   }
   ```
3. **Without using generics you can**:

   - check that the class object is `widget.class` and cast it and call the methods directly
   - call the methods using reflection